# Fourier Series Transform Recover Original Signals

Tags: transform, signals, fft, spectrum

Suppose I have three complex waveforms (consisting of many sinewaves): A, B and C. Each one has the following frequency: 550, 600, 700 Hz respectively.

Now I add the three signals i.e. do a superposition to get signal D.

My aim is to get back the three original signals A, B and C separately.

I have plotted the Fourier spectrum where I get the main peaks at 550, 660 and 700 Hz. There are other smaller peaks. How will I know which peaks associate with which waveforms so that I can recreate the original waveforms A, B and C ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If A, B, and C are not pure sine waves, what you want to do is not possible without additional information.  Suppose A is a sum of sine waves with frequencies 100 and 200 Hz,
B with 300 and 400 Hz, and C with 500 and 600 Hz.  Now consider signal D with frequencies
100 and 300 Hz, E with frequencies 200 and 500 Hz, and F with frequencies 400 and 600 Hz,
each component with the same phase and amplitude as the components of A, B and C.
(A+B+C) will have the same FFT as (D+E+F), so you can't tell them apart.

Comment: Agree. But when I listen to the combined three waves I can distinctively find ot that there are three waves. If I can hear it then there must be a way to separate the waves using a program.

Comment: @user: Perhaps the signal you're listening to has special properties that make it easy to distinguish the A, B, and C components -- e.g. each of A, B, and C takes the form of a strong fundamental plus a series of weaker harmonics.  That would fall under the "additional information" that I alluded to in my answer -- but the problem, as you've stated it, is not solvable in general.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to realise that you need to apply a [window function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) prior to the FFT, otherwise you will get artefacts in the frequency domain from the effect of the implicit rectangular window that you are applying to your time domain data. A good general purpose window function is the [Hann (aka Hanning) window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hann_window).

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing which technology you're using (a DSP chip, fftw, etc.) it's impossible to give you implementation details. But yes, apply a fast Fourier transform, and then assuming that you want to reconstruct three pure sine waves at 550, 600 and 700, the FFT will give you the amplitude and phase for each. Then a simple sine expression of the form `y=a*sin(wt+p)` will reconstruct the signal. "a" and "p" are the amplitude and phase from the FFT, and w=2*pi*f, where f is 550Hz, 600Hz, or 700Hz.

Comment: I am just using fast fourier transform's equation and writing codes.The main problem is that I do not want to reconstruct pure sine waves. Remember that each of the waves A, B and C consist of many sine waves. E.g A could be a square wave, B a triangular wave etc and my aim is to reconstruct them from signal D as explained above

Comment: If A, B or C is a square wave, triangle wave or anything except a sine wave, then you can't reconstruct it from only one frequency in the spectrum. You need its harmonics as well. Firstly, I recommend that if you're using C/C++/C#/pretty much anything except an embedded system, you use an FFT library like FFTW. Secondly, read http://cnx.org/content/m0041/latest/ . For the 550Hz wave, you must take the fundamental at 550Hz as well as a decent number of harmonics at 2*550, 3*550, 4*550, 5*550, etc.

Comment: From the Fourier Series each of the frequency is multiplied by a constant factor like you rightly pointed out. But how will I know what to multiply each frequency with. The factor could be anything and not necessarily 2,3,4,5... (like you pointed out above i.e. 2*550, 3*550...). Please note that from waveform D I will need to reconstruct the three signals A B C which I do not have any a priori information about. I just said square and triangular waves as an example. But they could be anything.

Comment: If they can be absolutely anything, your problem is impossible to solve. But if you restrict reconstruction to something that may only be an approximation based on the harmonics of each fundamental, you may get adequate results. By the above I meant that you must check the FFT output for the phase and magnitude at 550, 1100, 1650, 2200, etc. up to a reasonable number of harmonics (perhaps 16. perhaps less or more depending on your noise and bandwidth).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to add any form of complex signals? Do they have a pattern? If you want to retrieve any form of signal, it will be impossible. But in some cases, that you have a restrict material, you can work on that. In melodyne,for instance, they can separate some material of pitch-defined instruments: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFCjv4_jqAY

Comment: Like Reinderien and you are mentioning above it would be possible to achieve this if I know the pattern of A B or C. But the point is that I have to idea what it is. I am just given waveform D. From that I need to reconstruct the three signals. When I look at the Fourier Spectrum I do see lots of harmonics but I do not know which one to pick to get each of the three waves i.e. A B or C.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to retrieve A, B or C if you are completely clueless about them...A B or C can be a infinite set of possible signals!